# hash value not matching for output file with [contenthash] and bundled file inside node build folder in webpack 5 SSR

Tags: webpack-dev-server, bundling-and-minification, webpack-5

Application is not able to point to the correct build file from index file because the hash appended file inside node build folder is having different hash.
My webpack config output looks like below
`output = { filename: '[name]-bundle.[contenthash].js' chunkFilename: '[name].[contenthash].js' }`

Now index file inside the dist folder requires the bundled file like below
`bundelFilePath = path.resolve(__dirname, './node/main-bundle.**someHashValue**.js')`

My HTMLWebpackPlugin config
`const htmlWebpackPlugin = new HTMLWebPackPlugin({ template: path.join(__dirname, '../src/App/index.html') filename: './index.html' })`

The someHashValue is different from the hash being used inside the webpack build process, I am taking the webpack internal hash value from stats by accessing `stats.stats.hash[1]` and replacing the main-bundle with this hash appended value, however this **stats** hash value is different from the **contenthash** being used by the webpack 5.

How can I make both the hash same, i.e. [**contenthash**] value and webpack internal hash from **stats**

I tried setting `optimization.realContentHash` to `true`
I also tried setting `hash` value to `true` in `HTMLWebPackPlugin` config.